# WP Как получить данные соцсетей об пользователе?

Tags: php, wordpress

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как на фронт страниц вывести эти данные, которые задаются в админке пользователя? Пробовал получить через [get_userdata](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_userdata) но там почему-то не показало этих полей.

Comment: Используйте [get_user_meta()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_user_meta). Тут можете либо получить все meta пользователя, используя только 1-й параметр и не указав остальные, либо можете вывести что-то конкретное. Пример для фейсбук: `get_user_meta($user->ID, 'facebook' , true);`.

Comment: спасибо, помогло. Странно что они в  get_userdata() не отобразились

Comment: `get_userdata()` возвращает не все meta, а только определенные поля.